# Meteor subscribing based on specific template

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am working on meteor page where I am subscribed to two different sets up published data. I am subscribing to these in my router.

** Router **

```
@route 'chat',
        path: '/chat/:room_name'
        notFoundTemplate: 'home'
        loadingTemplate: 'Loading'
        waitOn: ->
        Meteor.subscribe('rooms')
        Meteor.subscribe('messages', @params.room_name)
        data: ->
            if Meteor.user()
                Rooms.findOne({room_name: @params.room_name})
        action: ->
            if @ready()
                @render()
```

Meteor is acting exactly as it should. By this I mean, whenever updates to `rooms` or `messages` are made, both of the templates on my page are updating their data. What I need is to separate this.

I.e. When an update to `rooms` is made, only my `rooms` template updates, and when an update to `messages` is made only my `messages` template updates.

I am assuming that I need to place my subscribes in specific areas to get this to happen, but I am not sure where to put them.

Comment: This may be unrelated, but your `waitOn` should return an array if you do indeed want to wait on both. Something like: `waitOn: -> [Meteor.subscribe(...), Meteor.subscribe(...)]`

Comment: I would suggest `Template.myTemplateName.created` hook.